# RAM issue with Dell XPS 1640

Tags: memory, dell-xps, sodimm

I have this laptop from 2009

- N07X1604
- STUDIO XPS 16 : INTEL CORE 2 DUO T9900(3
- MEMORY : 4096MB (2X2048) 1067MHZ DDR3 DU

As you see, it comes with 2 modules of 2gb 1067MHZ DDR3.
Now I have searched in the documentation here 
http://support.euro.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/sxl16/en/index.htm

http://support.euro.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/sxl16/en/sg/sg_en.pdf on page 63

so it seems that it supports 8gb ram. but a single 4gb seems unsupported?

When I insert the two 4gb ddr3 1066mhz modules the disable sound button is on and the increase volume button is on and the decrease volume button is blinking. the system does not boot. With the old memory, it boots.

So is 8gb ram possible? or not?
a lot of websites (which sell ram) say that the xps 1640 can have 8gb ram.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your laptop only supports 4GB

> Studio XPS 1640 1 GB, 2 GB, 3 GB, and 4 GB

The other two models of this series do support 8GB

> Studio XPS 1645/1647 1 GB, 2 GB, 3 GB, 4 GB, and 8 GB

There is nothing you can do to make it support 8GB.  I hope you can get a refund on the memory you purchased.

Comment: isn't it rare that a notebook cannot get a memory upgrade after purchase?

Comment: @JP yes and no. It depends on the CPU and motherboard combination. Take it into account next time you buy a machine

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound: I came via a search for EXACTLY the same issue and you've really helped. :)

Answer (score -1):

I've similar problem. According to Intel chipset PM45 do support up to 8GB.
The problem is a memory modules compatibility. It seems that only one who do the job is 
Samsung: DDR3 1066MHz // 4GB 2Rx8 PC3-8500S (07-10-F2) // M471B5273BH1-CF8

Comment: So you are saying that my 3 year old Dell XPS 16 can support up to 8gb? Have you tested this?